# How can I pretty-print an axiom in the OWL API with labels instead of IRI remainders?

Tags: owl-api

I have an application that presents axioms in a list-like fashion, where the user is allowed to switch between different OWLObjectRenderer implementations (such as the DLSyntaxObjectRenderer). Is there any way, without too much hacking around (string replace etc), that would allow me to print the entities labels instead of the IRIs or IRI remainders? (OWL API 4)

Answer (score 2):

Protege implements the same feature in `PrefixedOWLEntityAnnotationValueRenderer`, it looks straightforward enough to copy across to a non-Protege project.

Comment: Thanks Ignazio. As always.